# Replace JPanel with ScrollingImagePanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I have a program which looks like this:
[image]this.

In the whole frame I have different panels. One of them is the "Preview" one which inside may have some jLabel.

On some click I want to change it to be able to fit inside a TIFF image. The best way of working with TIFF images that I've found is using JAI. Specifically I've followed example on page 22:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-5413-10/806-5413-10.pdf

In this way for really big TIFF Images I can resize more or less easily and show them.

That works great when I do it in a new window, but when I try to put it in the same frame as my program all looks like a mess.

How could I manage to put it in the exact same position and size that the other panel was before?

Thank you!

UPDATE: This is what I'd tried but what I get here is not really what I want, as the new panel is not in the old position but starting in the left top corner. And I don't see other option to modify the panel but to just hide it.

```
FileSeekableStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileSeekableStream(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", stream);
    Interpolation interp = Interpolation.getInstance(Interpolation.INTERP_BILINEAR);
    ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
    params.addSource(image1);
    params.add(0.25F);         // x scale factor
    params.add(0.25F);         // y scale factor
    params.add(0.0F);         // x translate
    params.add(0.0F);         // y translate
    params.add(interp);       // interpolation method

    RenderedOp image2 = JAI.create("scale", params);

    int width = image2.getWidth();
    int height = image2.getHeight();

    ScrollingImagePanel panel = new ScrollingImagePanel(image2, width, height);

    jPanelPreview.setVisible(false);
    Frame [] currentFrame = ProgramUI.getFrames();
    currentFrame[0].add(panel);
```

Comment: Your details are vague and you haven't posted any code, so its hard to know how to answer this question.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm sorry. I'm new in netbeans GUI and I don't really now which code is that relevant. As at the beginning I just build the UI graphically and then I modify the code for different actions, and the code is not so straight forward to share like XML in android without pasting the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I manage to put it in the exact same position and size that the other panel was before?

When you create the frame you don't add a panel to the frame.

Instead you add a JScrollPane to the frame.

Then you can add any Swing component to the scroll pane by using:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( anyComponent );
```

Scrollbars will appear as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Rectangle to work as a viewPort. I use it for scrolling  games and works:

```java
public void paintComponent( Graphics g, Rectangle viewPort ) {

    //imageSource coordenates:
    int sx1 = viewPort.x ;
    int sy1 = viewPort.x ;
    int sx2 = sx1 + viewPort.width ;
    int sy2 = sy1 + viewPort.height;

    g.drawImage( imageSource, 
            0, 0, 
            viewPort.width, 
            viewPort.height, 
            sx1, sy1, syz, sy2, 
            null 
    );
}
```

The viewport is what is shown. From this see if it helps.

As for ScrollingImagePanel, I never heard of it, but it seems interesting, but the principle must be the same. I will study the book you shared.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)